# " wrong number of arguments" error in frame class initialization in wxRuby

Tags: ruby, user-interface, wxwidgets, wxruby

I am trying to find my bearings using wxRuby, and am using [this, perhaps outdated, tutorial](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2007/11/getting-started-with-wxruby-gui-toolkit.html) with ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]

This:

```
class MinimalApp < App
  def on_init
     Frame.new(nil, -1, "GUI Mockup").show()
  end
end
```

works: brings up an empty window.  However, when I try to add a frame to the window, as so:

```
class MyFrame < Frame
  def initialize()
  super(nil, -1, 'My Frame Title')
 end
end
```

and change "Frame.new(... " to "MyFrame.new"  I get the following error:

```
C:/.../wxTest.rb:8:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (3 for 0) (ArgumentError)
    from C:/.../wxTest.rb:19:in `new'
    from C:/.../wxTest.rb:19:in `on_init'
    from C:/.../wxTest.rb:24:in `main_loop'
    from C:/.../wxTest.rb:24:in `<main>'
```

At this point I am kind of stuck.    I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so seconds after posting, I answerd my own question.  The problem was that

```
 MyFrame.new.(nil, -1, "Multipass GUI Mockup").show()
```

sets the options twice, or something.  Changing it to

```
 MyFrame.new.show()
```

did the trick.

D'oh!